# NSArrayController remove:nil - understanding the nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Dumb question on my part, so I apologize for not being able to grasp this.

With an NSArrayController, you can send it a `remove:` message. If I have objects selected and send it `remove:nil`, those objects are removed. The docs simply describe the message argument `remove:sender` where sender is "Typically the object that invoked this method."

Could someone explain (or point me to an explanation) on what `sender` is or should be used for in this context?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want to use that. Every action method takes an argument `sender` for general purpose, even in the concrete case it makes no sense. I. e. you might have one action method for different buttons and decide reading the sender reference, what code to execute.

`-remove:` (`NSArrayController`) *always* removes the *selected* object(s), even you pass an object reference. It simply does not take care of this parameter. If you want to remove a specific object, use `-removeObject:`.